# Book Search dynamic web application

Tags: javascript, html, css

This web program name is Book search by using html, css, and javascript. In this code how can i do http GET request to searchInput element and how can i put bootstrap spinner to html searchInput element. Please explain and help me. According to this code two steps are not getting, the two steps are

1. When a value is entered in the HTML input element with id searchInput, x books option is selected in the HTML select element with id selectDisplayCount, an HTTP GET request with a valid url parameters title and maxResults should be made
2. When a value is entered in the HTML input element with id searchInput, x books option is selected in the HTML select element with id selectDisplayCount, an HTTP GET request should be made to fetch and display x book items

```js
let searchInputEl = document.getElementById("searchInput");
let spinnerEl = document.getElementById("spinner");
let searchresultsEl = document.getElementById("searchResults");
let selectDisplayCountEl = document.getElementById("selectDisplayCount");
let bookcount = selectDisplayCountEl.value;

let formData = {
    count: "10 Books",
};

function createAndAppendSearchResult(result) {
    let {
        title,
        imageLink,
        author
    } = result;
    let resultItemEl = document.createElement("div");
    resultItemEl.classList.add("country-card", "col-6", "mr-auto", "ml-auto", "d-flex", "flex-column");
    searchresultsEl.appendChild(resultItemEl);

    let imageEl = document.createElement("img");
    imageEl.classList.add("image", "mt-auto", "mb-auto");
    imageEl.src = imageLink;
    resultItemEl.appendChild(imageEl);

    let authorEl = document.createElement("p");
    authorEl.classList.add("author-name");
    authorEl.textContent = author;
    resultItemEl.appendChild(authorEl);
}

function displaySearchResults(searchresult) {
    for (let result of searchresult) {
        let titleName = result.title;
        if (titleName.includes(searchInputEl.value)) {
            createAndAppendSearchResult(result);
        } else {
            searchInputEl.textontent = "No reuslts found";
        }
    }
}

function searchBook(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        let url = "https://apis.ccbp.in/book-store?title=kalam&maxResults=30" + bookcount;
        let options = {
            method: "GET"
        };
        spinnerEl.classList.remove("d-none");
        searchresultsEl.classList.add("d-none");
        fetch(url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonData) {
                searchresultsEl.classList.remove("d-none");
                spinnerEl.classList.add("d-none");
                console.log(jsonData)
                let {
                    search_results
                } = jsonData;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
                displaySearchResults(jsonData.search_results);
            });
    }
}
selectDisplayCountEl.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    formData.count = event.target.value;
    console.log(formData.count);
});
searchInputEl.addEventListener("keydown", searchBook);
```

Comment: Please help me there was some code modification i cant get to modify in http GET request

Answer (score 0):

When the HTTP GET request is successful, then the searchResults element should consist of HTML image elements with src attribute value as the value of key 'imageLink' and HTML paragraph elements with text content as the value of key 'author' from HTTP response